# The correct use of the word Reformulation

Tags: nouns

Noun or Verb?

In the first sentence-

> And although the **reformulation** model sounds attractive, the industry is not littered with success stories.
>
> And although the **reformulated** model sounds attractive, the industry is not littered with success stories.

Which one fits better **reformulation** or **reformulated**? Why?

Maximum number of sentences using the word in question have used the Noun form-**reformulation**, but I felt Verb form **reformulate-ed** fits better.

> New Labour was not about a representation of traditional right-wing policies - it was about a **reformulation** of politics.
>
> New Labour was not about a representation of traditional right-wing policies - it was about ****reformulating**** politics.

Comment: To me, “reformulation model” would be a model which has some kind of reformulation as one of its key properties. “reformulated model” on the other hand suggests that the model itself was reformulated. Both re valid, and I have no clue as to which one would be more appropriate in that context, since there is too little context in that one sentence. I somehow miss a question attached to the second pair of sentences, but both of those sound correct and express the same thing.

Comment: @MvG That answers it.

Answer (score 2):

*Turning my comment into an answer.*

To me, “reformulation model” would be a model which has some kind of reformulation as one of its key properties. “reformulated model” on the other hand suggests that the model itself was reformulated. Both are valid, and I have no clue as to which one would be more appropriate in that context, since there is too little context in that one sentence. I somehow miss a question attached to the second pair of sentences, but both of those sound correct and express the same thing.